# MINECRAFT : Failed to login : The authentication are currently down for maintenance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please please someone help me , Whenever I try to connect to a multiplayer server on minecraft it says : Failed to login : The authentication are currently down for maintenance
PLEASE HELP!!! I NEED TO PLAY

Comment: I'm guessing that the authentication are currently down for maintenance..

Comment: @LoboDemon: That was my guess too, but https://help.mojang.com/ suggests that they're currently up. Nonetheless, pretty badly done question given that the answer is (theoretically) there in the error message.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is exactly what it says on the tin: **the authentication servers are down for maintenance**.

This generally means that they've had to get the servers off the line so they can make improvement work to it. There's nothing that anyone else can do about it until the servers come back online.

Comment: So you cant get on servers too ?? just checking as I have a few mates who are on it

Comment: @Sniperrrrrrrrrr Typically when the authentication servers go down, no NEW login events can be made. But if other people had joined a server *before* the authentication servers went down, they are typically unaffected until they attempt to re-connect

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the authentication servers go offline as it says in the error message. It varies when they go back up.

Comment: That site seems to be off-line, new one here: https://minecraft-techworld.com/status

Answer (score 0):

The servers will come back on, and its not the end of the world. Just wait it out, as it can go from a few seconds, to a few hours. Try restarting Minecraft, as by the time it is re-opened, it may have been resolved. If this fails, Just wait, and they will return to normal, and you will survive.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the *[authentication servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication_server)* are down for maintenance.  Authentication refers to the process of recognizing your username and password and making sure you are an authentic user.  This is something only Mojang can do, as they are the ones who administered your password.

Other multiplayer *[game servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_server)* may still be online, but these servers are not the same as *authentication servers*.  If a game server is online and you try to log in while the authentication servers are down, you will not be able to play because Mojang will not be able to verify that you are a registered user.  You will have to wait until the servers are back online before you can log in (this is usually not very long as Minecraft is in high demand).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with servers going offline. This is something to do with the firewall on your computer - something is blocking minecraft from working properly.

Servers go down for like 5 minutes at a time, but during this time NO one can join. Since your friends are online, that shows that there's something going on with your computer.

Comment: The question really makes it seem like there's a server problem...

Comment: _Servers go down for like 5 minutes_ What? They can go down for however long they are offline for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think its the firewall and this problem happened to me, I have Minecraft on all 3 of my computers and 1 doesn't work (the best one).